# CreateJS fails certification for Windows 8 apps

Tags: javascript, windows-8, createjs

I have completed my Javascript Game/App, and after having the build run with no errors or warnings, I was certain the Certification SDK would pass me with flying colors. Instead it game me two failures, both related to the CreateJS libraries that several tutorials recommend for developing Win 8 JS Apps. Specifically I am getting:

```
preloadjs-NEXT.min.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems
easeljs-0.5.0.min.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems
```

and

```
easeljs-0.5.0.min.js is not properly UTF-8 encoded. Re-save the file as UTF-8 (including Byte Order Mark)
preloadjs-NEXT.min.js is not properly UTF-8 encoded. Re-save the file as UTF-8 (including Byte Order Mark)
```

Do I need to do something to "prep" these libraries so I can pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save each file using File -> Save As then click drop-arrow on the Save button and select Save with Encoding.  Choose UTF-8 as your encoding for in the new dialog and that should fix your problem.

Comment: Certainly the second group of "errors" makes that clear. Not sure why I should have been getting Syntax errors as well because of the encoding selected?

Comment: well, it does day "or other problems" :)  Not sure why it is reported that way...